# Declare a dynamic 2d string array and define it in a separate globals.c file causes error: Undefined reference to 'NAME'

Tags: c, malloc

I think there is two reasons why I'm having so much issues with this, or why I'm still getting errors are:

1. I need to rely on argc to determine how much memory, but that isn't avaliable in other .c files, so I had to malloc in a function and pass argc in.
2. I wrote my entire code with `filePath` defined as `filePath[100][PATH_MAX]` because I couldn't be bothered with the malloc stuff until I was done with everything, only realising now that's probably the dumbest thing I could of done. You learn from mistakes I guess..

So:

Right now in my .h file:

```
extern char** filePath;
extern void mallocForFilePath(int);
```

In my globals.c file:

```
void mallocForFilePath(int size){
    filePath = malloc(size * sizeof(char*));
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        filePath = malloc(PATH_MAX * sizeof(char*));
    }
}
```

In main when calling:

```
mallocForFilePath(argc - 2);
```

Right now, when trying to `make` with this, nothing seems wrong in terms of the memory allocation, however I'm getting multiple errors saying `undefined reference to filePath` from all the different .c files I have that uses it. This is why I'm concluding that it's my memory allocation that's the problem because it's clearly defined.

Comment: just add `char** filePath;` in *globals.c* to define it because currentely you only declare it. However why do you need that global variable? just return the allocated array rather *void* in *mallocForFilePath*

Comment: @TomKarzes That's most likely a typo, fixed now

Comment: @bruno I thought I took care of the definition in the header file?

Comment: to use global var is dangerousn you can modify them every where, do `char ** mallocForFilePath(int size){...}`

Comment: the header file contains *declarations*, not *definitions*

Comment: @bruno isn't the line ```char** filePath;``` a declaration? Sorry I was in the middle of editing my reply, i meant declaration. Like how ```int a;``` is a declaration right? What makes ```char** filePath;``` a definition instead of a declaration? Or am I just understanding this all wrong?

Comment: `char** filePath;` is a definition, `int a;`is a definition

Comment: @bruno It did make it work though which im more confused about. And your second comment, you mean to change function type from void to char**?

Comment: yes I propose you to do to not have the global var, that also allows to call the function any number of times and to each time to get the new array, using a global var you cannot do that without loosing the previous allocation (memory leak possible)

Comment: Right right, I'll look into that, thanks

Comment: ok, I voted to close for typo